# Can a linux dummy network device work permanently as a real network interface?

Tags: networking, network-interface, vlan

Or does it need a service or systemd to bring it up every boot?  I want to manufacture, while learning, a whole NIC schematic virtually in my host to route packets with purpose and host some services on different internal IPs for sake of tracing packets and an IPS involved.

Is a dummy device reloaded on boot if created with `ip link add device type dummy`?  I know I need also to `modprobe dummy` along with that but how to set that at boot too?

Such as I want to use nginx to reverse proxy from my static WAN IP to all the desired services on differing IPs and set in the services running them that that NIC is that's IP.. If using a dummy device will (for example) prosody xmpp server bring it up on it's own on it's reserved and configured IP address?  I am using Debian 10 server and Arch Linux desktop.

Comment: that doesn't sound like a job for `dummy`, but for `tun` or `tap` interfaces, and they can be created and set up like you set up your "regular" interfaces. Actually, this even more sounds like a use case for Linux (network) namespaces; are you aware of `podman` or `docker`?

Comment: @MarcusMüller it is something Docker can do certainly I would think?  I didn't know TUN/TAP, thanks very much.  I want to run various web services on fake NICs and ip route them together

Comment: yeah, sounds like `podman` or docker. (I prefer podman, no strange daemons, they have separate "pods" as concept, which really means "a shared network between these few containers" and you can export the whole network and container setup into a systemd service script, which you can have automatically run at boot. Docker on the other hand is older, more popular, and "strange daemon" also means "starts automatically and sets up the things you've configured".)

Comment: @MarcusMüller what do you think of LXC containers?  I would otherwise probably go with Docker because most of my stuff is dockerized also.

Comment: well if you already use docker!

Comment: I do not actually use docker.  but I think it's probably about time i do now.

Comment: then start with podman instead :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out from my friend in XMPP chats that dummy interfaces are not brought up on boot and one would have to set scripts for boot time in a systemd service in order to bring up a dummy device and/or use a script on boot.  I'm aware that a device will need a service.